# Lower the input voltage for a buck-boost converter

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter

I have a design with a buck boost converter (TI [TPS63900](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63900.pdf?ts=1646831460165&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.de%252F).) Its maximum input voltage is 5.5V The device works down to 2.7V.

Currently the device is using a three AA alkaline battery pack (max 4.5V.)  I would like to know if it is possible to add a redesign for the device to connect it to a four AA alkaline battery pack (maximum 6V) but still use the total power capabiity of the battery pack down to 2.7V.

The requirement would be to enable the device to work from 6V down to 2.7V.

Is there a solution?

Comment: What's the input current (drawn from the battery) at full load?

Comment: Taking an estimated peak current at the output of 350mA @ 3Vout, and given we are down to 2,7V at the input, the input current drawn shall be about 400mA.

Comment: If you put a silicon diode before the input of the device this will bring the input down to ~5.4V for 6V battery voltage. But you'll not be able to take advantage of the circuit when the battery is down to 2.7V because the input will be ~2.1V. Plus, the losses will not be negligible. So a possible option is to use a buck converter which steps down the input to 2.7V regardless of the battery voltage. Or you can build a comparator-based "smart" circuit that shorts the aforementioned series diode when the battery voltage is less than 5.5V.

Comment: @RohatKılıç but if you use a buck converter to make sure your buck-boost is alwas in boost mode, you might as well just use a different buck-boost instead of the additional buck, or just a buck + a boost.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, you're right. Putting a buck converter before the buck-boost here makes the existence of the existing buck-boost non-sense.